# How do I replace EXISTS and NOT EXISTS with JOIN in SQL so I can translate it to relational algebra?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-algebra

I want to replace EXISTS and NOT EXISTS in the following query:

```
SELECT pokemon_name FROM sinnohdex s
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM hoenndex h
     WHERE s.id = h.id)
AND EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM johtodex j
     WHERE j.id = s.id);
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
SELECT pokemon_name FROM sinnohdex s
LEFT JOIN hoenndex h ON s.id = h.id
INNER JOIN johtodex j ON j.id = s.id
WHERE h.id IS NULL;
```

My goal is to later "translate" the query into relational algebra.
I don't know if this is even accurate.
The idea is to write the query only with joins. 
Is this right?

Comment: These are easily found faqs. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT distinct pokemon_name 
  FROM sinnohdex s JOIN johtodex j ON j.id = s.id
  LEFT JOIN hoenndex h ON s.id = h.id
 WHERE h.id is null
```

Comment: This is not equivalent because `pokemon_name` might be duplicated in `sinnohdex` and this would not return the duplicates.  That might be desirable behavior but it is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Then OP can use s.id also in select clause.

Answer (score 0):

Close, but not quite.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT s.pokemon_name
FROM sinnohdex s JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT j.id
      FROM johtodex j
     ) j
     ON j.id = s.id LEFT JOIN
     hoenndex h
     ON s.id = h.id
WHERE h.id IS NULL;
```

The `SELECT DISTINCT` is needed in the subquery to ensure that the `JOIN` does not product duplicates.

Removing duplicates *before* joining is usually more performant than removing duplicates after joining (although that might depend on the data).

Comment: RA projection returns unique tuples by its definition (p [2.1.2](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~zives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf)), so without knowlege of tables' structures there shoud be `DISTINCT` in top query.

Comment: @astentx . . . There is no need for `SELECT DISTINCT` in the outer query -- unless the OP specifically wants to delete duplicates in `sinnohdex` -- which is not part of the original question.  The `JOIN` cannot produce duplicate rows because of the `SELECT DISTINCT` in the subquery.  And the `LEFT JOIN` cannot because it returns rows with no matches.

Comment: It was about translation the query to relational algebra, where projection should return unique tuples according to the Codd's article. I consider this as essential part of the question (there was a doubt about accuracy). What about `distinct` in subquery: it's result is filtered out anyway, so it also depends on data.